# Solving PDE involving Hilbert transform numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations, integral-transforms

I'm trying to solve the following equation numerically:

$$u_{tt}-\mathcal{H}(u_x)=A^2_{xx},$$

where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert transform and $A$ is a prescribed forcing function which we assume takes the form $A(x,t)=f(x)\delta(t)$ for $\delta(t)$ the Dirac delta function. Note, the Hilbert transform is defined as

$$\mathcal{H}(u)(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{u(x')}{x-x'}dx'.$$

Finally, I would like to invoke a causality condition, such that for $t<0$, $u=0$.

Currently, I am trying to implement, for example,

```
NDSolve[{-(D[Convolve[u[t, xp], xp^(-1), xp, x, PrincipalValue -> True], x]/Pi) + 
    Derivative[2, 0][u][t, x] == -2*Sech[50*(-1 + t)]*Sech[x]^2*Tanh[x], u[0, x] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -10, 10}]
```

And Mathematica tells me

```
NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve.
```

Are there any work arounds for this? I am using Mathematica 7.

Comment: Please look at your code: because of all those formatting functions, it's impossible to parse. If you right-click on your expression and choose "Copy as Plain Text", it will copy-and-paste better.

Comment: To solve this problem with Mathematica, I believe it will be necessary to restrict the convolution integral to the same range as used in `NDSolve`, here `x = -10` to `x = 10`.  Even then, `NDSolve` probably is unable to solve an integro-differential equation.  So, it also may be necessary to convert the PDE into a coupled system of ODEs in `t`, as described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html).

Comment: It also appears to be possible to take the Fourier transform in `x` of the equation, reducing it to an ODE with x-dependent coefficients that could be solvable analytically, after which the solution could be transformed back.  If you wish to try this second approach, I suggest that you ask the question in [math.se].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment above, this problem can be solved by performing a Fourier Transform in `x`, solving the resulting ODE, and transforming back.  The [Fourier Transform of a Hilbert Transform](https://www.wavemetrics.com/products/igorpro/dataanalysis/signalprocessing/hilberttransform.htm) is given by `- I Sign[k] v[k]`, and the Fourier Transform of `D[u[x],x]` is `I k v[k]`, where `v` is the Fourier Transform of `u`.  Additionally, the Fourier Transform of the inhomogeneous term in the equation is

```
g = FourierTransform[Sech[x]^2*Tanh[x], x, k]
(* 1/2 I k^2 Sqrt[π/2] Csch[(k π)/2] *)
```

The resulting equation can be solved by

```
sol = FullSimplify[DSolveValue[{Derivative[2][v][t] + Abs[k] v[t] == 
    -2*Sech[50*(-1 + t)] g, v[0] == 0, Derivative[1][v][0] == 0}, v[t], t]]
(* (E^(-50 - I t Sqrt[Abs[k]]) k^2 Sqrt[π/2] Csch[(k π)/2] (E^(2 I t Sqrt[ Abs[k]]) 
   (50 + I Sqrt[Abs[k]]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/2 - 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], 
   3/2 - 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], -(1/E^100)] - I E^(t (50 + I Sqrt[Abs[k]])) 
   (-50 I + Sqrt[Abs[k]]) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/2 - 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], 
   3/2 - 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], -E^(100 (-1 + t))] + I (50 I + Sqrt[Abs[k]]) 
   (Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/2 +1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], 3/2 + 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], -(1/E^100)]
   - E^(t (50 + I Sqrt[Abs[k]])) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1/2 + 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], 
   3/2 + 1/100 I Sqrt[Abs[k]], -E^(100 (-1 + t))])))/(Sqrt[Abs[k]] (2500 + Abs[k])) *)
```

Not surprisingly, `InverseFourierTransform` cannot invert this expression.  It can, of course, be inverted numerically.  A typical plot of the expression is

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[sol /. t -> 10]], {k, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The real part is essentially zero (because the source term in the ODE is so narrow in time), and the imaginary part is antisymmetric.  Hence, a numerical sine transform can be used to invert expression.  For instance,

```
Quiet@Table[NIntegrate[-2 Im[sol] Sin[k x]/Sqrt[2 Pi], {k, 0, 10}], {t, 2, 18, 8}, 
    {x, 0, 20, .2}];
ListLinePlot[%, DataRange -> {0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, u}]
```

[image]

`u[x]` spreads and increasingly oscillates as `t` increases.